# Some feedback for the Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Some feedback:

It's annoying to have to paste the access token into the login dialog when testing in the Unity editor and then explicitly login each time.

(1) Would it be possible to add a field to the settings for an access token which would then be auto filled into the login dialog?

(2) When running on the device the user can be already logged in. It would be good if this could be replicated in the Unity editor so that flow can be tested without having to build to the device.

Answer (score 0):

1. It can't be done because the access token expires. You would have to change it every hour or so if I'm not mistaken.
2. For what I know, the Unity Editor can't hold on to a FB session the same way Android / iOS can, so this isn't an option either

Comment: 1. You can extend your token for 2 months. I have done this and pasted it into EditorFacebookAccessToken.cs to auto-fill the dialog, but I was just thinking of a more general solution that didn't involved modifying SDK code.

Comment: Just want to add that I came up with a solution for (2). I have an initial scene that loads first in the editor which allows me to login to Facebook. My initial game scene is the loaded so as far as the game is concerned it is starting with Facebook already logged in - just like on a device.